# I built a python package and uploaded to pypi. It can be installed but not imported: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

I built a python package and uploaded to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pillaralgos). It installs just fine, however on import I get `ModuleNotFound` error. The error was replicated in brand new conda environments, on different machines (Ubuntu, MacOS, Windows. Although all in (new) conda envs). The last time I had this error was because the folder was incorrectly named, however that is not the case here. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pillargg/twitch_chat_analysis/tree/pypi_reorganize/pypi) on branch and in folder that was used to build the whl.

Any ideas?

Package was built and installed using

```sh
python3 -m build
python3 -m twine upload dist/*
pip install pillaralgos
```

```sh
(pillar_env) jupyter-pomkos@jupyterubuntu:~$ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 24 2021, 21:46:12) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>> import pillaralgos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillaralgos'
>>>
```

It shows up in `pip list`

```sh
(pillar_env) jupyter-pomkos@jupyterubuntu:~$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------------------
# Truncated
pexpect            4.8.0
pickleshare        0.7.5
pillaralgos        1.0.1
Pillow             8.2.0
pip                21.0.1
```

`sys.path` does include the directory that the library is installed in.

```
(pillar_env) jupyter-pomkos@jupyterubuntu:~$ python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Feb 24 2021, 21:46:12) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/jupyter-pomkos/.conda/envs/pillar_env/lib/python38.zip', '/home/jupyter-pomkos/.conda/envs/pillar_env/lib/python3.8', '/home/jupyter-pomkos/.conda/envs/pillar_env/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/jupyter-pomkos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/jupyter-pomkos/.conda/envs/pillar_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

`pip show` says it was installed in the correct env and dir.

```sh
(pillar_env) jupyter-pomkos@jupyterubuntu:~$ pip show pillaralgos
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: pillaralgos
Version: 1.0.1
Summary: Algorithms for Pillar. Currently includes "mini" algorithms, nothing too sophisticated.
Home-page: https://github.com/pillargg/twitch_chat_analysis/tree/pypi_reorganize
Author: Peter Gates
Author-email: pgate89@gmail.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/jupyter-pomkos/.conda/envs/pillar_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

`ModuleNotFoundError` appears in jupyter console, in jupyterlab notebook, and in the terminal python. Confirmed that the kernel is pointing at the correct conda directory (although I don't think this troubleshooting was necessary, since the error was replicated on different machines):

```sh
(pillar_env) jupyter-pomkos@jupyterubuntu:~$ nano ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pillar_env/kernel.json
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/jupyter-pomkos/.conda/envs/pillar_env/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Pillar Env",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current [*`setup.cfg`*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pillargg/twitch_chat_analysis/cdb37e7c3d55dda0febbf22573f7475150c607b4/pypi/setup.cfg) looks like this:

```
[options]
package_dir =
    = pillaralgos
packages = find:
# ...

[options.packages.find]
where = pillaralgos
```

Comparing this with your project directory structure, it seems to me like you should change to something like this:

```
[options]
packages = find:
# ...
```

If I am not mistaken, the `package_dir` field as well as the whole `[options.packages.find]` section are not necessary.

Comment: I went ahead and switched to using `poetry` (posted as an answer), but tested your recommendation and it does work! So I'm assuming the `package_dir = pillaralgos` would define a subdir within the already exiting pillaralgos directory, and that's why my new folder structure worked with the default `python3 -m build` command. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. `package_dir` is for cases where the top-level packages are not right next to `setup.py` but in another directory (usually it is a `src` directory).

Answer (score 0):

Switched to `poetry` for all package building/publishing, they seem to have their head on straight.

That said to run with python's inbuilt `python3 -m build` and then `python twine upload dist/*` commands:

- Make sure all folders have `__init__.py` in them, locally and on github
- Make sure the folder structure is correct <--- this was the issue

Folder structure for default python command should be:

```
|-- pypi
     |-- src  # <---- this folder can be named pillaralgos, but still needed another pillaralgos subfolder
          |-- pillaralgos  # <----- this is needed
               |-- helpers
                    |-- __init__.py
                    |-- data_handler.py
               |-- __init__.py
               |-- algoXX.py
     |-- LICENSE
     |-- pyproject.toml
     |-- README.md
     |-- setup.cfg
```

`poetry` worked out of the box. Folder structure:

```
|-- pypi
    |-- pillaralgos  # <---- note that poetry didn't require an additional subfolder
        |-- helpers
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- data_handler.py
            |-- graph_helpers.py
            |-- sanity_checks.py
        |-- __init__.py  # must include version number
        |-- algoXX.py  # all algorithms in separate files
    |-- LICENSE
    |-- README.md
    |-- pyproject.toml  # must include version number
```